# Simple React-multi-carousel example fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, react-multi-carousel

I'm trying to run a basic usage of `react-multi-carousel`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Carousel} from 'react-multi-carousel';


export function MyComponent(props) {
  // ...

  return (
    <Carousel>
      <div>Item 1</div>
      <div>Item 2</div>
    </Carousel>
  );
};
```

But I'm getting `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of 'MyComponent'.`

I've installed `react-multi-carousel` with `npm i react-multi-carousel`.  What am I doing wrong?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use default import as the error suggests `import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel"`.